# when a computer is plugged in and off,RTC still using the battery?

Tags: battery, clock, cmos

when a computer is plugged in to a power source 
and off,RTC still using the battery?
or maybe the RTC "understand" that there is a better power source,the outlet?
the question applies to both laptops and desktops,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so because the RTC will work with no battery present, it just won't have a correct time.  You can observe this by removing the battery, booting the system, and looking at the time in the BIOS - it still works.

[The datasheet](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/10wi-cs140/pintos/specs/mc146818a.pdf) for the original chip responsible for providing this function in early PCs, the Motorola MC146818a, has a section "POWER-DOWN CONSIDERATIONS" where it implies something on the motherboard is responsible for moving it from system power to battery power--and a pin on that chip is provided so that nothing messes with the chip during the power transition.

So at least the original chip didn't use the battery until the motherboard, powersupply, or some component switched it (and kept the STBY pin off).

The MC146818a was not the only RTC chip used in early PCs, but likely any different chips in PC clones worked the same exact way for compatibility--until that function was pulled into integrated chipsets.  There may be some chipsets that diverged from the MC146818a's operation but I've never heard of any PC that wouldn't  turn on without a battery unless it was related to the firmware settings also getting reset - because they used to be stored in the RAM bytes of that same chip.

This [article from Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000006488/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html) says a bad CMOS battery will make the time inaccurate, and cause default CMOS settings to be loaded, but no other ill effects, and that's dated 2020, so I assume nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

No. When the computer gets external power, the internal powersource, such as the CR2032 battery is internally disconnected in order to avoid charging and discharging the battery.

In case of a capacitor, the capacitor is still being used with external power on, but its being charged at the same time until its maximum state is reached, then its switched to an alternative circuitry similar to with a CR2032 battery.

This is useful in case you need to replace the CR2032 battery. You ensure the PSU is connected so the motherboard receives current, then you can safely replace the CR2032 battery in order to not lose your settings.

Answer (score -1):

No power = it can't run. If it is running it may be running temporarily on a backup battery while it finishes a task after power taken away, I don't think it would work like that though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).